# What type of series is $A_1 + A_2 n + A_3 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am solving a coding problem and I break it down to a point where I get a series like this:
$$A_1 + A_2 n + A_3 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + A_4 \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{2\cdot 3} + A_5 \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4}$$

Now can this series be further broken down to some formula that is faster to calculate as n can be greater than $10^5$ so calculation of factorial is going to take lot of time. I figured it out that each of the variable part is one of the figurate numbers. So I think there might be some formula to calculate it faster. Any help on how to solve it or where I can learn more?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific? Would you like a closed form, or a name? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: done with my question now

Comment: Do you mean just those $5$ terms or an arbitrary number of them?

Comment: I think you accidentally wrote A3 two times and wrote A4 instead of A5.

Comment: aribitrary number of them...I tried adding \ldots but it added dots from a new line so I skipped it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $c_k$ is the coefficient of $A_k$, then $c_1 = 1$ and $c_{k+1} = something \times c_k$.

Comment: so some sort of recurrence relation?

Comment: Not **quite** a recurrence, because the $something$ depends on $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as a sum (in your example, $N=2$)
$$S = A_1+A_2n+\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!k!} A_{k+3}.$$

If I don't know what the $A$'s are more specifically, it is hard to simplify this. However, the sum without the $A$'s can be evaluated:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!k!}=\frac{(N+n)!}{N!n(n-1)!},$$ if that is of any help.

Comment: A's can be any number as they come from an input array..

Comment: If there is no systematic relationship between the A's, then I'm afraid you can't skip the computations.